# Get more than one author's posts with REST API

Tags: posts, rest-api

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?author=1
```

gives me author 1's posts.

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?author=1&author=5
```

gives me only author 5's posts.
Is there any way to get 2 different author's posts with one request?

Comment: Did you try `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?author=1,5`

Comment: oh, i didnt try that. Its worked by the way. Thank you!

Comment: @birgire can you post that as an answer?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Sure, posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `author` parameter in your request, seems to be mapped to the `author__in`  parameter in `WP_Query` that runs behind the rest-api call here, where a comma separated input:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?author=1,5
```

is translated to an `array( 1,5 )` input for `author__in`.